# coordinate tensor with respect to the standard basis vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, bilinear-form

Consider the bilinear form $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\phi(v,w)=\langle(1,0,0)^T,v \times w\rangle$$
Then what is the coordinate tensor with respect to the standard basic vectors?

Comment: Can you see what is the value of the form when you substitute basis vectors for $v$ and $w$?

Comment: Thank you even though I don't understand your comment very well. Sorry for this naive question.

Comment: A first step might be to write out $v\times w$ in terms of the vector's components.  Given the Question's age, I'm not sure if the Original Poster will have sufficient interest to supply more evidence of effort or other context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard basis, $\phi=v_yw_z-v_zw_y=v_iT_{ij}w_j$ (see $r=p_iT_{ij}q_j$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tensor#Second_order_tensors_in_three_dimensions)) with$$T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & -1 & 0\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link.